# Sbt Triggered Execution: detect watching mode stopped

Tags: sbt

I have a hot-reloading plugin based on Triggered Execution.
I updated to version 1.5.0 and i can't detect when watching mode is stopped.

This log is what i got "[info] Received input event: CancelWatch."

Have you any idea how detect when triggered execution is stopped?

Thanks!